# Ruby on Rails in SpringSource tool suite?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ide

I have been using Grails for some time now, but in school they are making us use Ruby on Rails.  I have been trying to find an extension for ruby on rails for STS as there is for Grails, but I have failed. The only thing that comes close is a plugin so i can use ruby code in my Grails app using JRuby. I just want to make sure that a fully integrated extension DOESN'T exist.

If that is the case, what would be the graphical IDE way of developing in ruby on rails, the same way one would use STS for Groovy on Grails development?
(preferably free :) )

Comment: It's "Grails", not "Groovy on Grails".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Aptana Studio](http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download) is the best and free IDE for ruby on rails.

Answer (score 2):

Try JetBrains [RubyMine](http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/), it's an IDE for Ruby and Rails.

Answer (score 1):

Old versions of Netbeans got a good support for language, but no longer updated for new releases.

I like JetBrains.

Comment: Last i checked (Netbeans 7.0.1) Ruby support was available via plugin, easily added via the Tools | Plugins menu option.  Still a decent free option, although I've moved on to Sublime Text these days.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.easyeclipse.org/site/home/  will allow you to build Rails framework apps. Look in the new install listing and I 'm sure you will find the url for Ruby and Rails. The type name is now under DLT Dynamic Languages Tools. RDT is a bit old and the EasyEclipse uses that.
Try yhis for radrails org.nexb.easyeclipse.radrails of course you know namespaces like this are backward. The best I could come up with for that is http://www.nexb.com/corp/. Or my STS has Juno - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno  and look under Programming Languages DLT Ruby to get started.

Also these guys might be able to help you https://www.facebook.com/groups/10463298884/